# "Service not available" while sending email from code

Tags: c#, gmail

A code which generates an email to me, every 30 minutes, with some text messages sometimes fails while running. 8 out of 10 messages get sent but 2 fail generating the below response.

The error message: `Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: sorry, You email could not be sent at this time. Please contact the administrator. (#5.7.1)`

Any idea why this happens? And what is the solution for this?

Comment: doesn't look like the full error message, going to have to provide more details and show your code.

Comment: Are you directly connecting to the mail server, or handing the mail to a local mail server which can and will queue it should the remote mail server not be available?

Comment: With this code I am directly connecting to the mail server.